# Hover feature and Link shifted

Tags: css, menu, hover

I am new to coding, and I am making a home page. I was trying to get the black and white hover feature on the images of my home pages. However, when I hover my mouse over the image, it does not work. It is only until you hover to the left of the image that the image will turn from color to BW. Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```css
 @font-face {
        font-family: "p22-underground";
        src: qzo1okq;
    }
    
    
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: -125px;
     margin-right: -70px;
     float: left;
    }
    
    
    .Marlon {
     position: absolute; 
      margin-top: -275px;
      margin-left: 15px;
    
    }
    
    /*B&W*/
    .blue {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    }
     
    .blue:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    
    .blue {
    
        position: relative;
        background-position: left top;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        text-align: center;
    
        
    }
    /*B&W*/
    .Tammy {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    }
     
    .Tammy:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
      display: block;
    }
    .Tammy {
    
        position: relative;
        background-position: left top;
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        text-align: center;
    
       
    }
    
    
    /*B&W*/
    .Tacos {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    }
     
    .Tacos:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    .Tacos {
    
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        margin-top: -623px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        max-width:100%;
       text-align: center;
    
    }
    /*B&W*/
    .Glasses {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    }
     
    .Glasses:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    .Glasses {
    
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        text-align: center;
    
     
    
    }
    /*B&W*/
    .Door {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
    }
     
    .Door:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    .Door{
    
        position: relative;
        background-position: right top;
        margin-top: -623px;
        Margin-left:700px;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        text-align: center;
    
    
    }
    
    
    .Social {
    
     position: relative;
        text-align: center;
     inline: block;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        top:-25px;
        bottom: 0px;
        margin:auto;
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    body {
        background-image: url("http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/background.jpeg");
    
    }
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 150;
        padding: 80;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 200px;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: "p22-underground";
        font-weight: "500";
        font-size: 150%;
    
    }
    
    li {
        float: none;
        color: "#fcf8de";
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
         bottom: 12px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        
    
    
       
    }
    
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: "#fcf8de";
        text-align: center;
       padding: 14px 16px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    footer {
     
    
        height:10px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top:100px;
        text-align:left; 
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding-top: 14px;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: "p22-underground";
        font-weight: "300";
        position:static;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qzo1okq.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
     <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Marlon Coding.html">
      <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/cactus.png" alt="Cactus Vector" width="100" height="90">
      </a>
    </div>
     <div class="Marlon">
      <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Marlon Coding.html">
      <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Marlon Vector.png" alt="Marlon Vector" width="450" height="550">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <ul> 
    <center>
    <h1 style="font-p22-underground-sc, sans-serif;font-style:normal; font-weight:500; font-size:80% "</h1>
      <li><a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Philosophie.html" style="color: #fcf8de; text-decoration: none;">PHILOSOPHIE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Menu.html" style="color: #fcf8de; text-decoration: none;">MENU</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Nous Trouver.html" style="color: #fcf8de; text-decoration: none;">NOUS TROUVER</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Avis.html" style="color: #fcf8de; text-decoration: none;">AVIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Contact.html" style="color: #fcf8de; text-decoration: none;">CONTACT</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </center> 
    <div class="opacity">
    <div class="blue">
    <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Philosophie.html">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/blue car.png" alt="BlueCar" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="Tammy">
    <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Avis.html">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/tammy Lunch.png" alt="TammyLunch" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="Tacos">
    <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Contact.html">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/tacos.png" alt="Tacos" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="Glasses">
    <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Menu.html">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Glasses.png" alt="Glasses" width="300" height="310">
    </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="Door">
    <a href="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/Nous Trouver.html">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/door.png" alt="Door" width="300" height="620">
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>      
    <footer>
      <p1><font color="#fcf8de">CALL: 01 40 60 12 12</font></p1>
    <div class="Social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/restaurantmarlon">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Vector" width="20" height="25">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/restaurantmarlon/">
    <img src="http://ac.aup.edu/~a94241/instragram.png" alt="Instargram Vector" width="20" height="25">
    </a>
    </div>  
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the problem is the size of your <div> in your css:
blue, Tammy, Door, ... can't have max-width:100%;
add to all this class 
border:1px solid red;
and you could this taht all of your classes are too big, this why the on Hover work too early.

Comment: You don't use the right method,
to help you;
https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: Thank you so much! Incredibly helpful!